# Not Detecting a Particular Wifi Network

Tags: wireless

Until yesterday ubuntu was detecting my wifi network well. I had been working with it for about a month. Now suddenly it detects all other wireless networks except mine. Can you please help me with the solution.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What was the last thing you remember doing (e.g. installed updates or drivers or upgraded ubuntu to a new version)? Restart the wifi router, restart the computer. See if it helps. If you use a usb dongle with a usb extension cable, try without the cable. If you don't use a wifi usb, try with a wifi usb dongle.

Comment: Does it help to delete the connection you have defined for it? Rename it?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Namely, that  Ubuntu 12.04 would detect all other networks except the two networks that I have been connecting without any problem for the past 3 months.

To be precise, Ubuntu would not detect the wifi network automatically nor would it show the network when I clicked the wifi icon on the top right of the Ubuntu status bar.

Since I am a novice at linux/Ubuntu I searched through the Internet, with this questing being the most relative, without any quick solution.

I solved the issue by going to `System settings` >> `Network` >> `Wireless` >> unfolding the drop down menu `Network Name` (it did not indicate my network there as well) >> select the last option `Other...` >> then unfold the `Connection` drop down menu and you will find all the previous network connections you have made.

Another option is to click on the wifi icon on the main status bar, click on the `Connect to hidden network` and click on the drop down menu `Connection` where you should find the previous established connection.

It worked for me.